# Converting or transposing Multi Index dataframe index column to header identifier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose, multi-index

I currently have a multi index dataframe where two columns are acting as the indexes, column 'Date', and 'Product'. And two additional columns acting as values, columns 'Sales', 'Cost'.
.
However, I would like to convert one of the index columns as the header identifier, while the other index column acts as the row identifier.

`df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10-31','10-31','10-31','12-31','12-31','12-31'],'Product':['Apple','Pear','Banana','Apple','Pear','Banana'], 'Sales':[1, 0.8, 1.2, 2, 0.9, 1.7], 'Cost':[0.5, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.7]})`

Setting 'Date' and 'Product' as index columns:

`
df2.set_index(['Date', 'Product'], inplace=True)

df2
`

The multi index dataframe looks like this:

| Date | Product | Sales | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-31 | Apple | 1 | 0.5 |
|  | Pear | 0.8 | 0.3 |
|  | Banana | 1.2 | 0.6 |
| 12-31 | Apple | 2 | 0.4 |
|  | Pear | 0.9 | 0.4 |
|  | Banana | 1.7 | 0.7 |

But I want to transpose the 'Product' index column as the header identifier, whilst still keeping the 'Data' index column as the row identifier. Something like this:

```
         | Apple              | Pear               | Banana   |
```

| Date | Sales | Cost | Sales | Cost | Sales | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-31 | 1 | 0.5 | 0.8 | 0.3 | 1.2 | 0.6 |
| 12-31 | 2 | 0.4 | 0.9 | 0.4 | 1.7 | 0.7 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), then swap levels of `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and sort `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with first level:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10-31','10-31','10-31','12-31','12-31','12-31'],'Product':['Apple','Pear','Banana','Apple','Pear','Banana'], 'Sales':[1, 0.8, 1.2, 2, 0.9, 1.7], 'Cost':[0.5, 0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.7]})
```

---

```
df = (df2.set_index(['Date', 'Product'])
      .unstack()
      .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
      .sort_index(axis=1, level=0, sort_remaining=False))
print (df)
Product Apple      Banana       Pear     
        Sales Cost  Sales Cost Sales Cost
Date                                     
10-31     1.0  0.5    1.2  0.6   0.8  0.3
12-31     2.0  0.4    1.7  0.7   0.9  0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = [[1.0, 0.5], [0.8, 0.3], [1.2, 0.6], [2.0, 0.4], [0.9, 0.4], [1.7, 0.7]]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['10-31', '12-31'], ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana']])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Sales', 'Cost'], index=idx)
```

`df2`

```
                Sales   Cost
10-31   Apple   1.0     0.5
        Pear    0.8     0.3
        Banana  1.2     0.6
12-31   Apple   2.0     0.4
        Pear    0.9     0.4
        Banana  1.7     0.7
```

---

**Code**

```
(df2.unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
.reindex(columns=['Sales', 'Cost'], level=1))
```

result

```
Product Apple           Banana          Pear
        Sales   Cost    Sales   Cost    Sales   Cost
Date                        
10-31   1.0     0.5     1.2     0.6     0.8     0.3
12-31   2.0     0.4     1.7     0.7     0.9     0.4
```